# Java daylight saving time does not work for distant past (UPDATE: It does)?

Tags: java, date, dst

The following piece of code:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens").inDaylightTime(new Date(200, 8, 14));
```

returns `true`, much like it does for the year 2011. However, [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST) was only proposed 100 years or so ago, and applied even more recently. Is the time in the year 200 considered DST, or is this a Java quirk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mistaken. It works as expected when you use the date `new Date(-1700, 8, 14)` (which is year `200`). The constructor you are using is adding `1900` to your year. You are actually using year `2100`.

Check the [Date constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) api.

Comment: The Java Date API at its best! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the timezone database. Some locales come with ridiculously detailed time instructions (such as recording 8-minute changes in UTC offsets back in the 1800s), whereas others are content with being useful for times reasonably close to the date they are created -- perhaps because the compiler of the database did not have easy access to information about when the current scheme was instituted and what came before it, and therefore coded it as "applies to all times before such-and-such".

Comment: +1 Timezones before about 1970 can be horribly arcane and complex, especially in developing countries, where local solar time was used and offsets like 5m39s could apply prior to uniform adoption of timezones.  As Henning says, it all depends on what the TZ database maintainers decide to do with early dates.

Answer (score 1):

The date you are testing is

> Sep 14, 2100 12:00 AM

Not in past, but in future! To print exact date, try with

`DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
            DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date(200, 8, 14))`

Answer (score 0):

For fun I tried this in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 with Java 7. Looks like it works correctly.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( 200, 8, 14, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Athens" ) );
boolean isDST = !( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Athens" ).isStandardOffset( dateTime.getMillis() ) );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "isDST: " + isDST );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 0200-08-14T00:00:00.000+01:34:52
isDST: false
```