# Java 8 LocalDateTime and Strange Zone Behaviour

Tags: java, excel, date, time, format

I'm a bit confused when using the LocalDateTime from Java8.

#### What I'm trying to do

- I have a Date (java.util) object
- I want to convert it to a LocalDateTime
- I want to format the LocalDateTime to get the time as HH:mm

#### What I have done

```
LocalDateTime ldate2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime ldate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("CET"));
System.out.println("Date : " + date);
System.out.println("LocalDateTime CET : " + ldate);
System.out.println("LocalDateTime " + ZoneId.systemDefault() + " : " + ldate2);
```

#### The Result is

```
Date : Sun Dec 31 23:30:00 CET 1889
LocalDateTime CET : 1889-12-31T23:30
LocalDateTime Europe/Paris : 1889-12-31T22:39:21
```

#### My Question

What I expect as a final result is **23:30** which is working fine with `ZoneId.of("CET")` but I would like to avoid to specify the timezone to use the system one `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. In this case *Europe/Paris*. But then I get **22:39** instead. I could easily understand an offset of 1 hour but here it sounds really strange to me.

Using `SimpleDateFormat` with the original date is working fine but the code will probably run in a multi thread environment, so I need a thread safe solution.

Could someone explain me this behaviour? Is this expected or am I doing something wrong (or am I not understanding something obvious :))?
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Edit :

The issue is related to the year (1889) that is quite old, but it's the year used in Excel for time representation.
Sample of code to see the issue : http://ideone.com/kaHaAz

Comment: [Could not reproduce.](http://ideone.com/sSNf7x) Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Yes right, I just tried also with a sample like this and it worked on my computer. The full picture is a bit more complex. I'm creating an axis2 message builder that is reading an excel file using apache POI. The date is the content of a cell. Maybe the issue is more related to this, but I still don't get why

Comment: We can't help you if we're not able to reproduce the problem. You need to find a way to drill down to a specific snippet of code that's problematic. Often that attempt alone will cause you to discover a detail you've overlooked. If not, at least we'll have something to work with.

Comment: Got it the time representation of Excel is in 1889. So to reproduce it's [in this example](http://ideone.com/TADUrp) When I run it on my computer I have the same behaviour (22:39) in Europe/Paris zone

Comment: I don't see anything problematic there. FYI, you can set the time zone in ideone using `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));`, as in my updated test.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, using this you can see the issue now : http://ideone.com/kaHaAz

Comment: I didn't know that Excel handles years before 1900, see also http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm

Comment: It's not really a question of handling dates before 1900, in this case it's really the time representation in Excel. If you just have a columns with times like 00:30, 00:45, 01:00.... they are represented has dates in 1889 (1889-12-31 00:30, 1889-12-31 00:45....)

Comment: Is it really the year 1889 or rather the year 1899 (because Excel seems to use 1899-12-30 as epoch)? And how do you get your `Date`-instance? Via which API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Analysis and solution

The answer of @shmosel correctly mentions the different historical tz offset of Paris in 1889. [A good original source](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/europe) to confirm this:

> ```
> Zone  Europe/Paris  0:09:21 -       LMT   1891 Mar 15  0:01 
>                     0:09:21 -       PMT   1911 Mar 11  0:01 # Paris MT    
>                     0:00    France  WE%sT 1940 Jun 14 23:00
> ```

But this is only a tiny part of the whole truth. **It is important to understand the differences between `java.util.TimeZone` and `ZoneId` introduced in Java-8.**

**The new class `ZoneId` interpretes the rules of the underlying tzdb-repository such that all entries including the LMT-lines are queried.** LMT means "local mean time" and is an arbitrary invention of TZDB-maintainers when no exact historical timezone offsets are available. Those LMT-entries just represent a longitude-based offset calculation of the associated city/region and does NOT represent any real historical timezone offset. So please handle such offsets with greatest care: It is usually not how people at that time have looked at their local time. Keep also in mind that most people (or all) had not any sufficiently exact methods of time measuring available at those ancient times. **So the general approach to use timezone calculations for this far past is questionable.**

> Summary: `ZoneId` uses +00:09:21 as offset for year 1889.

However, you say you start with an object of type `java.util.Date`. Since this type does not represent a local calendar date or wall time but rather a moment, a timezone calculation cannot be avoided to obtain the wished local timestamp. The question now arises which type of timezone to use. In case of `java.util.Date`, the natural and most probable choice is NOT `ZoneId`, but the old class `java.util.TimeZone`. Especially true if you have got your `Date`-instance via other legacy APIs like Apache POI (a library allowing access to Excel-files).

You might think the internal rules of both `java.util.TimeZone` and `ZoneId` should be the same for a given tz-identifier like "Europe/Paris". But no, it is not the same. **The traditional class `TimeZone` cuts off all offset transitions before year 1900 and uses the current offset instead.**

1. In year 1889, the offset of `java.util.TimeZone` is +01:00 (current
   winter time in year 2017).
2. In year 1900 until 1911, the offset is +00:09:21.
3. After 1911 until June 1916, the offset is zero.

Therefore I suggest you to abandon the class `ZoneId` and to use the class `TimeZone` in order to preserve the original timezone calculation for every year in question. Practically you use the same tz-rules as applied in constructing the `Date`-instance. **Example for a solution:**

```
String input = "Sun Dec 31 23:30:00 CET 1889";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris");
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
Date d = sdf.parse(input);
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(tz.getOffset(d.getTime()) / 1000);

System.out.println(d); // Tue Dec 31 23:30:00 CET 1889

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d.toInstant(), offset);
System.out.println("ldt=" + ldt); // 1889-12-31T23:30
```

**Another subject regarding your year of 1889:**

The year 1889 is astonishing for me. As far as I know (my suspicion), Excel uses a date about ten years later as reference point, namely 1899-12-31. So clock times without any date will rather be modelled with respect to this epoch at the end of year 1899. Keep in mind that Excel models date and time just as double relative to Excel epoch.

Another detail indicates 1899 instead of 1889: The weekday of your 1889-12-31 is Tuesday, but the weekday of 1899-12-31 is Sunday so your input "Sun Dec 31 23:30:00 CET 1889" is not consistent. Please try to check how exactly you obtain your `Date`-instance and also check if you have not just done a typographical error here.

Comment: Thank you for this complete explaination. I tried SimpleDateFormat before using DateTimeFormatter, and you're right it's working fine. But in my memory SimpleDateFormat was not thread safe (that's also why joda time was so much used), did it change in Java 8?

Comment: You're also right about 1889, it's a typo it should be indeed 1899

Comment: @Nicolas If you're worried about thread safety, don't share a formatter between threads. Or synchronize before using.

Comment: @Nicolas `SimpleDateFormat` will never be going to be thread-safe (old design choice), so a new instance is necessary in case of multiple threads (or access via ThreadLocale - the best way performancewise). I have chosen it here - mainly for demonstration purposes - in order to directly create an instance of `java.util.Date` with the rules of `TimeZone`. If you are using Apache POI then that API will give you directly an instance of `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 3):

I have yet to find a source for this, but it looks like the offset in Paris in 1889 may indeed have been +00:09:21:

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("1889-12-03T10:15:30").atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")).getOffset());
// +00:09:21
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232851/1553851

Comment: Well then as I understand it's an expected behavior, an option could be then to move the date in the current year (as I just need the time in this case) in order to keep something as generic as possible.